# Ember 2 set select value in component

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, components, html-select

I have a little problem.

There is some component, which must render the form for editing model's record. And I need render it on listing page below each model's record.

There is a gist: https://gist.github.com/mxgoncharov/9f1b4cd52cac9173fd46

Problem: When I open it, all fields without select-tags are filled. If render e.g. groupId or another SELECT-tag's value as label it shows right (e.g. '6'). But select-tag doesn't show selected value, and all select-tags shows only prompt.

How can I redraw or refill select-tags? Maybe I did smth wrong?

Comment: Is fm-field extended from Ember.Select.View ? or an own implementation as component (because http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html is deprecated)? if it´s extended from Ember select view im missing "selection" instead of "value"

Comment: @ChristianStengel I think it's a custom component. I use this package https://github.com/Emerson/ember-form-master-2000. "value" works on save, if it's "new" page. And nope, "selection" doesn't work.

Comment: ok your right from the implementation the option is selected if value = optionValuePath "selected={{is-equal (if optionValuePath (get item optionValuePath) item) value}}>" please check if the values are identical also note there was a bugfix on 5 Nov to fix the is-equal helper

Comment: @ChristianStengel thx very much!!! Problem was in is-equal helper. It returns false instea true. You was right.